# How can I improve the speed of materialized view refreshes and reduce CPU usage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, postgresql-9.5, materialized-views

I have a crone job that runs every 10 min to sync data. For that, I am using a function to refresh the materialized view. Everything works fine but sometimes the cpu usage hits max.  When I run the query below, I get the refresh materialized view function using 23 percent of cpu. How can I improve the refresh materialized view process?

query used to find the cpu %

```
SELECT 
        pss.userid,
        pss.dbid,
        pd.datname as db_name,
        round((pss.total_exec_time + pss.total_plan_time)::numeric, 2) as total_time, 
        pss.calls, 
        round((pss.mean_exec_time+pss.mean_plan_time)::numeric, 2) as mean, 
        round((100 * (pss.total_exec_time + pss.total_plan_time) / sum((pss.total_exec_time + pss.total_plan_time)::numeric) OVER ())::numeric, 2) as cpu_portion_pctg,
        pss.query
FROM pg_stat_statements pss, pg_database pd 
WHERE pd.oid=pss.dbid
ORDER BY 7 desc
```

Here is my refresh function

```
-- FUNCTION: refresh_mat_view()

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS refresh_mat_view();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mat_view(
    )
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_1;   
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_2;  
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_3;  
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_4; 
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_5;  
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_6;  
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_7;   
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_8;  
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_9;
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_10;
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_11;
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_12;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: CPU utilization hitting 100% is not necessarily a problem. Reducing the utilization might just slow down the refresh process without any gain. Unless other concurrent work is prevented from completing in a timely fashion, don't worry about utilzation. Since you didn't provide the details of the views, it's implossible to make any meaningful recommendation to improve efficiency.

Comment: Some time I am getting this error :LOG:  skipping vacuum of "mat_view_7" --- lock not available . When the cpu utlilisation is high and on application side I am getting connection not available error. my max connection is not reached in that time.

Comment: There's a [`pg_ivm`](https://github.com/sraoss/pg_ivm) extension, but it's only compatible with version 13 and above. Overall version 9.5 support [ended in 2021](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Without any query plan, it’s impossible to optimize any. Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for the inner SQL statements? Then we can see what the mat view is doing. You need this for every individual mat view

Comment: Are you rebuilding the view from scratch?  Or only from incremental data?